# MongoDB: updating collection of objects to change owning side of reference

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, database, nosql

I have two collections, Group and User. Originally, my Group document contained an array of User references. But I've changed my mapping so that Users now hold a reference to a Group. I am wondering how I can write a query to update all the existing User documents to reference the group that is currently referencing them, then remove any references on the groups.

Comment: How about a reasonable question with real data? Should we guess your data?

Comment: There's an array of DBRefs on one side.. and i need to swap them to a field on the referenced doc instead. What else do you need to know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't notice the language you are using at first - I had to do something very similar in Python so here is my example code:

```
# I changed my collection names to users/groups hope I mapped them right :)
users = db.users
groups = db.groups

for u in users.find():
    grp = groups.find( { "users" : u['userId'] } )
    u['groups'] = [ g['groupId'] for g in grp ]
    users.save(u)
```

Basically, for every user, I look in groups to find a list of groups which contain userId in the array users, and I make a list called groups in u and when I save it adds an array of groups to users document.

Should be not hard to do it in PHP

$users = $db->users;
   $groups = $db->groups;

// find all users
   $ucursor = $users->find();

// iterate through users, find groups which have the user, 
   // update user with array of groups
   foreach ($ucursor as $u) {
       $gcursor = $groups->find( ... );
       foreach ($gcursor as $g) {
          ...
       }
   }

But this seems like a one time operation, you could do it in mongo shell using something similar to:

```
var users = db.users.find();
while (users.hasNext()) {
   u = users.next();
   var gs = db.groups.find({"users":u.userId},{"groupId:1}).toArray();
   db.users.update({"groupId":groupId},{$set:{"groups":gs}});
}
```

Comment: This adds the array referencing groups to users.  I assume getting rid of the array of users from groups is more straightforward. Just do for each group: db.groups.update({"groupId":10},{$unset:{"users":1}}) to remove users array from group with groupId 10.

Comment: oops, didn't notice the php tag

Comment: added some points regarding running this in mongo shell or PHP

Comment: The query for mongo shell is exactly what i was looking for. Thanks, worked like a charm.